# Is it possible to run replace on a list/subset of columns in a dataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

For example:

```
dataset['column_1'].replace(['(null)'],['0'],inplace=True)
```

replaces all of the 'error' strings in column one. But if I want to do that to a few specific columns right now I'm going:

```
dataset['column_1'].replace(['(null)'],['0'],inplace=True)
dataset['column_5'].replace(['(null)'],['0'],inplace=True)
dataset['column_7'].replace(['(null)'],['0'],inplace=True)
```

Is there a way to combine that and run the same replace on a list of column names?

I have tried doing this:

```
names = ['column_1','column_2','column_3','column_4','column_5','column_6','column_7']
dataset = pandas.read_csv('allvalues.csv', names=names)
dataset[['column_1','column_3','column_4','column_7']].replace(['(null)'],[0],regex=True,inplace=True)
```

but the columns are still being printed afterwards with the '(null)' string values.

Comment: What about defining a function or iterating over a list of strings?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [DataFrame.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) instead of `Series.replace()`:

```
dataset[['column_1','column_5','column_7']].replace(['error'],['0'],
                                                   regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I tired this, but unfortunately it's not replacing the values

Comment: @Acoustic77, can you post a small reproducible sample data set and your desired data set in your question?

Comment: the actual value I'm trying to replace is '(null)', maybe that has something to do with it?